# Labview : What is difference between VI Call Configuration and SubVI Node Setup?

Tags: labview

When I try to pop up a subVI, I usually use this configuration.

[image]

But, I realized I can call the subVI with this setting.

[image]

Now, I am feeling two configurations do the same work.

What is difference between two configurations?

Which configuration is recommended to call subVI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sub VI Node setup is NOT a method to call SubVI. It sets subVI properties such as to show front panel when called with some call method.

VI Call Configuration helps to determine when the subVI memory should load to RAM and when it should be released after the call.

Comment: Are there any problems when I use subVI node setup to call a vi on a higher vi, instead of vi call configuration?

Comment: SubVI Node setup is not a call method. It is popup to configure call options. You call a subVI either by placing it on higher vi or using async/sync call.

Comment: I understood, I was confused. Thank you.